# Firefox ignores child and jumps to parent on click event

Tags: jquery, firefox, cross-browser, click, parent

the following code is not working in firefox as desired however it works perfectly fine in chrome.

```js
$("#parent").click(function(){
 alert("parent")
});

$("#child").click(function(){
 event.stopPropagation();
 alert("child")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:500px;height:500px;background:red;" id="parent">
 <div style="width:200px;height:200px;background:green; font-size:200px" id="child">
 X
 </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the child, the click event of the parent is triggered in firefox, the child is completely ignored.

Am I missing something?

I tried to find the problem but there are mostly problems regarding propagation.

Comment: Open the developer tools (Firebug) and check the error message in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `event` is undefined in Firefox.  (In other browsers, it *may* default to the current event.)

To fix it, add `event` as the parameter to the `click` function:

```js
$("#parent").click(function(){
  alert("parent")
});

$("#child").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert("child")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:500px;height:500px;background:red;" id="parent">
 <div style="width:200px;height:200px;background:green; font-size:200px" id="child">
 X
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmmm so the defect is in the other browsers not Firefox, funny thing :)

Comment: Perhaps the other browsers are being "friendlier" than Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#parent").click(function(e){
  if($(e.target).attr('id') == 'child'){
    //it's child
  } else {
    //its parent
  }
})
```